# Determining time ranges within pre-defined shifts in MySQL

Tags: mysql, time

I'm working with a timecard database and trying to determine how much time for each punch falls into each one of three distinct shift periods.

```
For example
shift 1 = 7AM - 3pm
shift 2 = 3pm - 11pm
shift 3 = 11pm - 7am

Joe clocks in at 6:45AM and out at 1:45PM
```

15 minutes of this would need to be calculated as time on shift 3, but I'm not sure how to go about slicing out that bit of time in MySQL. All I have are a time in and time out field.

There are three shift periods:

```
Shift  TimeStart   TimeEnd
1      07:00       15:00
2      15:00       23:00
3      23:00       07:00
```

**Sample Data**

```
ID    TimeIn            TimeOut           Hours
100   2014-07-31 06:45  2014-07-31 13:45  7
```

**Desired Result**

```
ID    Shift  TimeWorked
100   1      06:45
100   2      00:00
100   3      00:15
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbf5f)

Comment: Show exactly (table structure) how you're storing the times.

Comment: Edited to include the structure

Comment: i don't understand exactly what you want, but I think you need: UNIX_TIMESTAMP, FROM_UNIXTIME, FROM_UNIXTIME_TO_SEC(), SEC_TO_TIME()

Comment: @KirkLogan I would suggest you read about normalization. You should only be storing `ID, Time, TimeType`, where in/out goes in `TimeType`.

Comment: @catalinetu most of those are useless considering that OP is storing in a `datetime`, not a Unix timestamp.

Comment: @Kermit All well and good, but I didnt pick the schematic, this is a dump from a clients database.

Comment: @KirkLogan I don't think I fully understand your requirements. Mind updating your question with some sample data and your desired result?

Comment: I elaborated further, does that all make sense?

Comment: @KirkLogan I edited your question. Please let me know if any of that information is not correct.

Comment: Take a look at the MySQL date and time functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: That is exactly correct, thank you! Sorry for not laying it out better.

Comment: Do you want this only in mysql?

Comment: Strictly MySQL and PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution for this using PHP.

What I did was loop through each punch, minute by minute, and determine what shift each one minute time span applies to. Within the loop, I increment one of 4 variable for shifts 1, 2, 3 or 0(no shift pay), and at the end, dump those variables to the database for the record being analyzed.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM source_filtered_timecard";
$result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
    $checkCount++;
    $shift1_hours = 0; $shift2_hours = 0;
    $shift3_hours = 0; $shift0_hours = 0;

    $time = strtotime($record['in_time']); 
    $time_out = strtotime('-1 Minute',strtotime($record['out_time']));

    while($time <= $time_out) {
        $mysql_time = date('G:i:s',$time);

        //SELECT SHIFT CODE THAT APPLIES TO CURRENT PIT//
        $query = "SELECT shift FROM shift_rules WHERE STR_TO_DATE('{$mysql_time}','%H:%i:%S') BETWEEN start_time_24 AND end_time_24 LIMIT 1";
        $current_shift_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($current_shift_set) == 1) {
            $current_shift = mysqli_fetch_assoc($current_shift_set);
            if($current_shift['shift'] == '1'){$shift1_hours++;}
            elseif($current_shift['shift'] == '2'){$shift2_hours++;}
            elseif($current_shift['shift'] == '3'){$shift3_hours++;}
            else{$shift0_hours++;}
        } else {
            $shift0_hours++;
        }
        //INCRIMENT TIME BY 1 MINUTE//
        $time = strtotime("+1 minute",$time);
    }

    $shift1_hours = $shift1_hours/60;
    $shift2_hours = $shift2_hours/60;
    $shift3_hours = $shift3_hours/60;
    $shift0_hours = $shift0_hours/60;

    //UPDATE TIMECARD ROWS WITH SHIFT HOURS//
    $query = "UPDATE source_filtered_timecard 
              SET shift1_time = {$shift1_hours}, 
                  shift2_time = {$shift2_hours},
                  shift3_time = {$shift3_hours},
                  shift0_time = {$shift0_hours}
              WHERE id = '{$record['id']}'";
    $update = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in PHP.  Looking at Joe's example, it is initially tempting to try to work out how his data maps onto the shift rules. However, I think it would be a neater solution to do it the other way around i.e. map the rules onto his data, until there is no data to classify.

The algorithm might go a bit like this:

- Joe's remaining time is 6:45 - 13:45

Let's map the first rule onto it (i.e. how much of this rule contributes to that range?):

- shift 1 = 7:00 - 15:00 (6:45 hours)

Now Joe's remaining time is:

- 6:45 - 7:00

Do the next rule:

- shift 2 = 15:00 - 23:00 (0 hours)

Joe's remaining time is therefore unchanged. And finally the last rule:

- shift 3 = 23:00 - 1d7:00 (0:15 hours)

There are a few things to note:

- The amount of worked time could be stored in an array (a "worked time set"). It starts off as a simple start and end, but if a rule removes a chunk of time from the middle, it may split into two starts and two ends
- When applying a rule, convert them to actual timestamps (i.e. a date and a time) so the wrapping to the next day works correctly
- Write a function that takes a worked time set, plus a rule start and end timestamp, modifies a worked time set, and returns a number of hours for the rule

Answer (score -1):

First you need to add day column for differentiate time from 23:59:59 to next day time.

id| shift_name | time_start | time_end | day
1   | Day Shift | '07:00:00' | '18:59:59' | 1
2   | Night Shift | '19:00:00' | '06:59:59' | 2

Procedure :

DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE sp_check_shift(IN intime time) PROC: begin IF(intime>='00:00:01' AND intime<='23:59:59') THEN IF ( SELECT 1 FROM tbl_shift WHERE time_start<=intime AND time_end>=intime AND day=1) THEN SELECT shift_name FROM tbl_shift WHERE time_start<=intime AND time_end>=intime AND day=1;ELSEIF ( SELECT 1 FROM tbl_shift WHERE time_start<=intime AND day=2) THEN SELECT shift_name FROM tbl_shift WHERE time_start<=intime AND day=2;ELSEIF ( SELECT 1 FROM tbl_shift WHERE time_end>=intime AND day=2) THEN SELECT shift_name FROM tbl_shift WHERE time_end>=intime AND day=2;END IF;ELSE SELECT 'Invalid Time' shift_name;END IF;END$$ delimiter ;